# nm, address = addr ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1), Django Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a personal project that is an E-Commerce made with Django Rest Framework and Vue.js. I have created a contact form and when I try sending it, it creates an error:

```
/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 96, in sanitize_address
    nm, address = addr
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

It seems like it needs some kind of additional value that it doesn't get from my views.py.

This is my Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone',
            'email',
            'subject',
            'message',
        )
```

This is my Views.py:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .models import Contact
from .serializers import ContactForm

@api_view(['POST'])
def contact_form_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = ContactForm(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            first_name = serializer.validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name = serializer.validated_data['last_name'],
            phone = serializer.validated_data['phone'],
            email = serializer.validated_data['email'],
            subject = serializer.validated_data['subject'],
            message = serializer.validated_data['message']

            print(first_name, last_name, phone, email, subject, message)

            context = {
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name': last_name,
                'phone': phone,
                'email': email,
                'subject': subject,
                'message': message
            }

            send_mail(
                subject,
                render_to_string('emails/contact.txt', context),
                email,
                ['emailThatItryToUse@gmail.com'],
                fail_silently=False,
                auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None, html_message=None
            )
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have checked through the console if the form information gets detected and it does. All of that I get via v-model="".

And this is my settings.py configuration for email:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'emailThatiTryToUse@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'accessPasswordforThatEmail'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

And this is the JavaScript for sending data into the backend:

```
  const data = {
      'first_name': this.first_name,
      'last_name': this.last_name,
      'phone': this.phone,
      'email': this.email,
      'subject': this.subject,
      'message': this.message,
  }

  axios
      .post('/api/v1/contacto/', data)
      .then(response => {
          this.$router.push('/')
          return response
      })
      .catch(error => {
          this.errors.push('Algo funciona mal')
          console.log(error)
      })
```

I really hope that you can help me with that. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the commas from `serializer.validated_data` assignment statements. That is, it should be `first_name = serializer.validated_data['first_name']` instead of `first_name = serializer.validated_data['first_name'],` (and so on)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if serializer.is_valid():

    first_name = serializer.validated_data['first_name'],
    last_name = serializer.validated_data['last_name'],
    phone = serializer.validated_data['phone'],
    email = serializer.validated_data['email'],
    subject = serializer.validated_data['subject'],
```

I believe the problem is caused by the commas at the end of these lines, which makes the assigned values into tuples.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was the problem. It happened because I was making different changes, copy-pasted from my older code and used as Object, then deleted object and added those declarations inline, and so on. It was just caused because of distration, for no reason. Thank you!